# Get hardcoded dropdown values from service instead of directly displaying in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-service

I have this html code.

```
<select ng-model="Type">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="10D">10 Days</option>
 <option value="20D">20 Days</option>
 <option value="30D">30 Days</option>
</select>
```

Instead of directly coding the dropdown values in html, i am trying to get this values from angualrjs service.

I created the following service

```
DayServiceMod.service('DayService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q, $scope) {
this.getDayDetails =function() {

    return [
    {DayValue: '10D' , DayDisplay: '10 Day'},
    {DayValue: '20D' , DayDisplay: '20 Day'},
    {DayValue: '30D' , DayDisplay: '30 Day'}

    ];
}

}]);
```

In the controller by providing proper injections of service. i tried to get day types as follows.

```
$scope.DayType = DayService.getDayDetails();
```

In the Html

```
<select ng-model="Type">
<option value="" disabled>Select Volume...</option>
<option ng-repeat="DayValue in DayType" value="{{DayValue}}">{{DayDisplay}}</option>
</select>
```

Can someone please let me know what i did wrong here.

Comment: Check the answer i have posted, you simply need to change your HTML part and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `ng-repeat` to something like this where you actually access the JSON property while setting the `value` and `display name` of the `<option>`. Everything is same, just for simplicity i have hard coded the option array inside the controller. The main change for you is the HTML.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller='FirstCtrl'>
<select ng-model="Type">
  <option value="" disabled>Select Volume...</option>
  <option ng-repeat="Day in DayType" value="{{Day.DayValue}}">{{Day.DayDisplay}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.selectedRegione = 'Mike';
    $scope.DayType =[
    {DayValue: '10D' , DayDisplay: '10 Day'},
    {DayValue: '20D' , DayDisplay: '20 Day'},
    {DayValue: '30D' , DayDisplay: '30 Day'}

    ];
});
```

For your simplicity and further experiment with this code here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mhu8wrsd/)

Comment: And upvote it as well. So that people can know it is fully accepted by you.

Comment: If you have anything else you can let me know,